# Rspec fails for Name has already been taken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to make rspec testcases. But, Rspec fails for Name has already been taken.

It seems "let" evalulated each time "product" called.

How can I fix it?

Console

```
./spec/models/spree/product_decorator_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken
./spec/models/spree/product_decorator_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
./spec/models/spree/product_decorator_spec.rb:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
./spec/models/spree/product_decorator_spec.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken
./spec/models/spree/product_decorator_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
./spec/models/spree/product_decorator_spec.rb:12:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
./spec/models/spree/product_decorator_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

product_decorator_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Spree::Product do

  context '#create' do
    let(:us) { create(:zone, name: "US") }
    let(:china) { create(:zone, name: "China") }
    let(:japan) { create(:zone, name: "Japan") }


    context "when a product has no ng zone" do
      let(:product) { create(:product, zones: [us, china, japan]) }

      it "should get ng_zones correctly" do
        product.ng_zones.should match_array []
      end
    end

    context "when a product has one ng zone" do
      let(:product) { create(:product, zones: [us, china]) }

      it "should get ng_zones correctly" do
        product.ng_zones.should match_array ["Japan"]
      end
    end

    context "when a product has two ng zone" do
      let(:product) { create(:product, zones: [us]) }

      it "should get ng_zones correctly" do
        product.ng_zones.should match_array ["China", "Japan"]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: seems your test db is not clearing after each spec. and you have validate uniqueness for zone name in your model.

Comment: Do the tests pass when you run them separately?

Comment: You should show us the relevant part of your product decorator and its validations. You could also try to make sure that you can create a product in `rails console` with the call you try to issue.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the `let` is evaluated with every `it` block. I'm assuming you have a uniqueness constraint on your `Zone` classes.

You have 2 possibilities

- Either build the variables in a `before(:all)` block and assign them to something like `@us`
- Clean up your database `after(:each)`

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the `Product#create` so, you won't need to really create `zones` for this particular test.

Instead you could just use `build_stubbed` method.

```
let(:us) { build_stubbed(:zone, name: "US") }
let(:china) { build_stubbed(:zone, name: "China") }
let(:japan) { build_stubbed(:zone, name: "Japan") }
```

This way, it's creation process are not going to rely on the database and also the validations for the `Zone` model and you have an awesome performance boost since you are not hitting the db for for each single test.

You can read about `build_stubbed` [here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-factory-girls-build-stubbed-for-a-faster-test).

Please let me know if it helps you somehow. ;)